# Prepared Statement query building not working when the parameters are setting in java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

I am trying to build a query by using PreparedStatement and i think something goes wrong when i used PreparedStatement because it return nothing. Then i tried passing direct sql query and it was success.
And same query i was run in Oracle SQL Developer and ,it was also success.

I need to know what is wrong with my code.

My Idea is something wrong sql query is building, when the parameters are set using PreparedStatement.

Here i am using Oracle as the back end.

```
public List<Hotel> getAvailableHotelsDA(ReservationDetails resevationDetails) throws SQLException, ParseException
{
    List<Hotel> hotelList  =  new ArrayList<Hotel>();

    int idCountry =  resevationDetails.getIdCountry();
    int idState =  resevationDetails.getIdState();


    String query =  "SELECT h.idHotel , h.Name , h.Description  FROM hotel h"+
                    " INNER JOIN contract c ON h.idHotel = c.idHotel"+
                    " INNER JOIN country cn ON h.idCountry = cn.idCountry"+
                    " INNER JOIN state st ON cn.idCountry = st.idCountry"+
                    " WHERE c.startDate <= TO_DATE(?,'yyyy-MM-dd') "+
                    " AND c.endDate >= TO_DATE(?,'yyyy-MM-dd') "+
                    " AND c.isCurrentContract=?"+
                    " AND h.idState = ?"+
                    " AND h.idCountry = ?"+
                    " GROUP BY (h.idHotel , h.Name , h.Description)";


    PreparedStatement prepStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try
    {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        format.setLenient(false);
        Date checkIn =  format.parse(resevationDetails.getCheckInDate());
        Date checkOut = format.parse(resevationDetails.getCheckOutDate());


        connection = DBUtility.getConnection();
        //connection = DBUtility.getMySQLConnection();
        prepStatement =  connection.prepareStatement(query);
        int count = 0;
        prepStatement.setDate(++count, convertFromJAVADateToSQLDate(checkIn));
        prepStatement.setDate(++count, convertFromJAVADateToSQLDate(checkOut));
        prepStatement.setInt(++count, CONTRACT_STATE.CURRENT.getValue());
        prepStatement.setInt(++count, idState);
        prepStatement.setInt(++count, idCountry);

        //prepStatement =  connection.prepareStatement("SELECT h.idHotel , h.Name , h.Description  FROM hotel h INNER JOIN contract c ON h.idHotel = c.idHotel INNER JOIN country cn ON h.idCountry = cn.idCountry INNER JOIN state st ON cn.idCountry = st.idCountry WHERE c.startDate <= TO_DATE('2015-02-25','yyyy-MM-dd')  AND c.endDate >= TO_DATE('2015-03-05','yyyy-MM-dd')  AND c.isCurrentContract=1 AND h.idState = 1 AND h.idCountry = 1 GROUP BY (h.idHotel , h.Name , h.Description)");

        resultSet  =  prepStatement.executeQuery();



        Hotel hotel;
        while(resultSet.next())
        {
            hotel =  new Hotel();

            hotel.setHotelID(resultSet.getInt("idHotel"));
            hotel.setName(resultSet.getString("Name"));
            hotel.setDescription(resultSet.getString("Description"));

            hotelList.add(hotel);
        }


    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Error : SQL Exception : Method : getAvailableHotels ");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        DBUtility.close(resultSet, prepStatement, connection);
    }

    return hotelList;

}
```

Comment: `TO_DATE` may not be expecting a `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: i changed  WHERE c.startDate <= TO_DATE('2015-02-25','yyyy-MM-dd') without passing the date value. Then it is working.

Comment: Then I would not try binding a `java.sql.Date` to the `TO_DATE(?, ` parameter, instead, try converting to a `String` in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd` and see if that works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to bind a `Date`, it makes no sense to call `to_date`.  `to_date` does not accept a `date` as an input, it only accepts a `varchar2`.  If you pass in a `date`, Oracle has to first implicitly cast the `date` to a `varchar2` then pass the `varchar2` to `to_date` in order to have the string converted back into a `date`.  The implicit `date` to `varchar2` conversion will use your session's `nls_date_format`.  If that happens not to match the explicit format mask you're passing in to `to_date`, you'll either get an error or you'll get a `date` you don't expect.

Since you are binding a `Date`, your query should just be something like

```
" WHERE c.startDate <= ? "+
" AND c.endDate >= ? "+
```

If there are time components in `startDate` or `endDate` that you want to ignore, you probably want to `trunc` the date (which may involve creating some function-based indexes).

Comment: You are saying that if i used **prepStatement.setString()** to bind the date in **to_date** ,it should be worked ?

Comment: @Tharinda_tpw - If you bound a string in the proper format, yes, the version that used `to_date` would work.

Answer (score 0):

i used below method to convert date and parse date without using **to_date** and it was success this time

```
private java.sql.Date convertFromDateStringToSQLDate(String dateString)
{
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = null;

    try 
    {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date dateNotFormat;

        dateNotFormat = sdf.parse(dateString);


        sdf.applyPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String dateFormatString = sdf.format(dateNotFormat);

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        Date dateFormat = (Date)formatter.parse(dateFormatString); 


        if (dateFormat != null)
        {
            sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(dateFormat.getTime());
        }

        System.out.println(sqlDate);

    } 
    catch (ParseException e) 
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sqlDate;
}
```

This is the query and binding...

```
    String query =  "SELECT h.idHotel , h.Name , h.Description  FROM hotel h"+
                    " INNER JOIN contract c ON h.idHotel = c.idHotel"+
                    " INNER JOIN country cn ON h.idCountry = cn.idCountry"+
                    " INNER JOIN state st ON cn.idCountry = st.idCountry"+
                    " WHERE c.startDate <= ? "+
                    " AND c.endDate >= ? "+
                    " AND c.isCurrentContract=?"+
                    " AND h.idState = ?"+
                    " AND h.idCountry = ?"+
                    " GROUP BY (h.idHotel , h.Name , h.Description)";


    PreparedStatement prepStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try
    {           

        connection = DBUtility.getConnection();
        //connection = DBUtility.getMySQLConnection();
        prepStatement =  connection.prepareStatement(query);
        int count = 0;
        prepStatement.setDate(++count, convertFromDateStringToSQLDate(resevationDetails.getCheckInDate()));
        prepStatement.setDate(++count, convertFromDateStringToSQLDate(resevationDetails.getCheckOutDate()));
```